# server pages in html getting data dynamically

Tags: php, apache

actually i have a search engine and i want to show my search results in html pages

for example

one method user can search on my site is visiting a url like

`http://mysite.com/search.php?q='KEYWORDS'`

but i want to make search query on my site in such a manner

`http://mysite.com/search/keywords.html`

while keyword.html is not a static page on my site but dynamically created at the time of search query
so how can i make this work using php or apache .htaccess file. i have googled it but can't find the answer

so plz help

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/) similar like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-z]+)\.html$ search.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php?query=$1.html
```

Note that this rule may affect other media files in your folder. So is better to move them elsewhere (in a subdomain).

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is make a form first

`use php`

The search_result.php should be something like this have a look

[for result file click here](http://submaza.com)